# Symfony2, Templating, Special variables from "settings"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I read on the net about custom global variables in TWIG templating, yes, I found there only static variables.

My problem is, I want to create a few global variables, which will have data from my <kbd>Settings.php</kbd> (+ also join controller to load this data). So it will in my **::base.html.twig** looks like this:

```
<title>{% block page_name %}settings.page_name{% endblock %}</title>
```

And for example my **AcmeContactBundle:Default:index.html.twig** looks like:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block page_name %}{{ parent() }} - Contact me{% endblock %}
```

So if I use `$settings->setPageName('My web')` my title will have this form: **My Web - Contact Me** in my **ContactBundle**.

**So, what I need** is how to create any some kind global variables in TWIG or something like this, where each this special variable will have information from any controller which will have variable `$settings` to parse in my **::base.html.twig** template (like normal controllers with rendering template with their variables). Is there any best effective idea to have to solve this?

Comment: I think you may need to break the question up so its more clear what steps you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a variable in your base template ( `::base.html.twig` in your case ):

```
{% set page_name = 'AwesomeCompany - ' %}

<title>{{ page_name }}</title>
```

Then in your template extending the base template you only need to override the variable or add something to it.

```
{% set page_name = page_name ~ 'Home' %}
```

... no need to override or create the block.

---

**Using a twig extension / global variable**

In order to get the value from your entity repository you can ...

create a Twig extension:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/AcmeExtension.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
    {
       $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return array(
            'page_name'=> $this->em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Entity')->findOneBy(array('..'))->getPageName();
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

Then register your extension as a service and inject the repository

```
# app/config/config.yml ... or load from a bundle-extension
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now you can ommit the static `{% set page_name ...` in your base tempalate because the variable will be available as a global aka. in all your templates.

Comment: But you can see 'AwesomeCompany - ' is an static value. I need to get this data from DB (by object Settings)

Comment: then create a twig extension registering a global variable using the `getGlobals()` method.

Comment: is there any example how can I use it with entities?

Comment: there you go - any questions left? or is it enough for a upvote/accept? :)